# Dynamic group_by argument based on a list, R, for loop/function

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

Using `dplyr`

Here is my dataset:

```
Class   Time    Honors  Grade    Total Students
Math    AM      Yes     PassFail    23
English AM      No      Letter      31
Science AM      Yes     Letter      22
Gym     AM      No      PassFail    26
Math    PM      Yes     PassFail    19
English PM      No      Letter      23
Science PM      Yes     Letter      24
Gym     PM      No      PassFail    13
Math    AM      Yes     PassFail    24
English AM      Yes     Letter      27
Science AM      No      Letter      28
Math    PM      No      Letter      21
English PM      Yes     PassFail    23
Science PM      No      PassFail    22
```

I want to run four queries, with four increasingly specific answers. The first query will have one group_by argument, the second two group_by arguments, three for the third and so on.

```
#query 1 
df %>%
  group_by(Class) %>%
  summarise(NewValue = mean(`Total Students`))

#results
    Class NewValue
    <chr>    <dbl>
1 English    26.00
2     Gym    19.50
3    Math    21.75
4 Science    24.0
```

The second query is the same basic calculation with one more group_by argument.

```
#query2
df %>%
  group_by(Class, Time) %>%
  summarise(NewValue = mean(`Total Students`))

#results
    Class  Time NewValue
    <chr> <chr>    <dbl>
1 English    AM     29.0
2 English    PM     23.0
3     Gym    AM     26.0
4     Gym    PM     13.0
5    Math    AM     23.5
6    Math    PM     20.0
7 Science    AM     25.0
8 Science    PM     23.0
```

And the pattern continues `#query3` will be

```
 df %>%
  group_by(Class, Time, Honors) %>%
  summarise(NewValue = mean(`Total Students`))
```

And `#query4` will be

```
df %>%
  group_by(Class, Time, Honors, Grade) %>%
  summarise(NewValue = mean(`Total Students`))
```

**Question:**

Is there a way to write one query and use a for loop to incorporate the increasing levels of detail in the `group_by` argument?

For example, the pseudo code below does not work; I was hoping there is a solution similar:

```
resultsarray <- data.frame()
Groupbysteps <- c( "Class", 
                   "Class, Time", 
                   "Class, Time, Honors", 
                   "Class, Time, Honors, Grade")

for (i in Groupbysteps) {
      resultsarray <- df%>%
                       group_by( Groupbysteps) %>%
                       summarise(NewValue = mean(`Total Students`))

 all <- rbind.fill(all, resultsarray)
}
```

Comment: The query has different columns. What do you want to fill with for missing columns? Can you show your desired output?

Comment: @Psidom _NAs_ are desired. I marked the answer below correct. It resulted in _NAs_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could work.

```
Groupbysteps <- c( "Class", "Time", "Honors", "Grade")

for (i in 1 : length(Groupbysteps)) {
      resultsarray <- df%>%
                       group_by(.dots = Groupbysteps[1 : i]) %>%
                       summarise(NewValue = mean(`Total Students`))

 all <- rbind.fill(all, resultsarray)
}
```

Following works:

Example data set

```
df <- iris[1:20, ]
colnames(df) <- c( "Class", "Time", "Honors", "Grade", "Total Students")
df[, 1] <- as.factor(sample(c("a", "b"), rep=T)) 
df[, 2] <- as.factor(sample(c("a", "b"), rep=T)) 
df[, 3] <- as.factor(sample(c("a", "b"), rep=T)) 
df[, 4] <- as.factor(sample(c("a", "b"), rep=T)) 
df[, 5] <- rnorm(20)
```

The code:

```
Groupbysteps <- c( "Class", "Time", "Honors", "Grade")
resultsarray <- data.frame()

for (i in 1 : length(Groupbysteps)) {

  resultsarray <- df %>%
    group_by(.dots = Groupbysteps[1 : i]) %>%
    summarise(NewValue = mean(`Total Students`))

  all <- rbind.fill(all, resultsarray)
}
```

Comment: This works really well. For anyone else looking at this answer. This uses `plyr`, `dplyr` and you must run `all <- data.frame()` in addition to what @Disco Superfly explained

Answer (score 1):

Try `syms` in rlang as shown:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

L <- lapply(1:4, function(i) df %>% 
                               group_by(!!!syms(names(df)[1:i])) %>% 
                               summarize(newValue = mean(Total_Students))
)
```

giving a list `L` of 4 data frames whose column names are:

```
> lapply(L, names)
[[1]]
[1] "Class"    "newValue"

[[2]]
[1] "Class"    "Time"     "newValue"

[[3]]
[1] "Class"    "Time"     "Honors"   "newValue"

[[4]]
[1] "Class"    "Time"     "Honors"   "Grade"    "newValue"
```

Comment: That output is interesting, I'm assuming there is a way to easily convert to a table?

Comment: I assumed that since you already showed how to do that in the question itself that it would not be necessary to repeat it in the answer but just to finish it off it would be `rbind.fill(L)`